# Git deployment: removing files when push files removed

Tags: deployment, git, hook

I have a *post-receive* hook to deploy my app in *webroot* when I push on *master* branch.
This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch..."
        git --work-tree=/var/www/mywebroot --git-dir=/home/myuser/myrepo checkout -f master
    else
        echo "Ref $ref successfully received.  Doing nothing."
    fi
done
```

The problem is that when I push any commit that deletes any file, the files were removed are not removed in webroot.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're trying to pull? checkout only swaps branches and updates the HEAD. Git pull will pull updates.

Answer (score 1):

You can add (using [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)) just after the `git checkout` line:

```
git -work-tree=/var/www/mywebroot --git-dir=/home/myuser/myrepo clean -fd
```

That will remove untracked files and folders.